# I cannot pass a primary key value from one form to other form in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I cannot pass a primary key value from one form to other form, and I am not using gridview

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_INSERT_DriverRegistration", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DriverReg_id", HF_Reg_Id.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", Fname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lname", Lname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", Email1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", Password.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", Gender.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", Mobile.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CNIC", CNIC.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", Address.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DrivingExperience", DrivingExperience.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@license", license.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Route", ddlRoute.SelectedItem.Text);

    con.Open();
    string result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
    con.Close();

    string id = HF_Reg_Id.Value.ToString();
    Response.Redirect("VanRegister.aspx?id= "+id);
}
```

I have 2 tables `DriverRegistration` and `VanRegistration`. When driver fills driver registration form and submit it then van registration form will open, and in `VanRegistration` table `DriverReg_id` will insert. So that's why I want to pass `DriverReg_id` through query string.

Stored procedure of `DriverRegistration` table

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SP_INSERT_DriverRegistration] 
    @DriverReg_id as int,
    @Fname varchar(50), 
    @Lname varchar(50), 
    @Email varchar(50), 
    @Password varchar(50), 
    @Gender varchar(50), 
    @Mobile varchar(50), 
    @CNIC varchar(50), 
    @Address varchar(50), 
    @DrivingExperience varchar(50),
    @license varchar(50), 
    @Route varchar(50)
AS BEGIN 
    IF @DriverReg_id = -1 --FOR INSERTION IF CONDITION TRUE 
       IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 DriverReg_id 
                 FROM DriverRegistration 
                 WHERE Fname = @Fname AND Mobile = @Mobile)     
       BEGIN
           SELECT -1    
       END
       ELSE BEGIN
          INSERT INTO DriverRegistration(Fname, Lname, Email, Password, Gender, Mobile, CNIC, Address, DrivingExperience, license, Route, CreatedOn, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn, IsActive, IsVerified)         
          VALUES(@Fname, @Lname, @Email, @Password, @Gender, @Mobile, @CNIC, @Address, @DrivingExperience, @license, @Route, GETDATE(), 1, null, null, 1, 0)

          SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()   
       END
    END
    ELSE BEGIN 
        UPDATE DriverRegistration 
        SET Fname = @Fname, Lname = @Lname, Email = @Email,
            Password = @Password, Gender = @Gender,
            Mobile = @Mobile, CNIC = @CNIC,
            Address = @Address, DrivingExperience = @DrivingExperience,
            license = @license, Route = @Route,
            UpdatedOn = GETDATE(), UpdatedBy = 1
        WHERE 
            DriverReg_id = @DriverReg_id 
    END
END
```

Comment: i want to pass id in van registration page           public partial class VanRegister : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConstring"].ToString();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
                {
                    HF_Reg_Id.Value = Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString();
                   // HF_DriverReg_id.Value = Request.QueryString["DriverReg_id"].ToString();}}}

Comment: Note that the `SP_` prefix is used to designate system stored procs and should be avoided in application procs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx).  Use a different prefix (or none at all) and follow to best practice of schema-qualifying objects to maximize performance.

Comment: You have an incomplete  question here. You haven't described the behavior specifically enough. You just say you "cannot pass". Does the redirect happen? Does the URL look correct? What code on the receiving page is responsible for retrieving the ID from the query string?

Comment: @mason i want to redirect the Van form in which one column is DriverReg_id but its insert -1 in DriverReg_id in Van form

Comment: You still do not have a complete question. Reread my previous comment. Show where `HF_Reg_Id` and explain why you think it should have a value.

Comment: @mason  <asp:HiddenField ID="HF_Reg_Id" Value="-1" runat="server" />

Comment: You see where you set `Value="-1"`? That's why you insert -1. If you expected differently, explain why.

Comment: no in driver table its insert correctly but in van tables its insert -1,

Answer (score -1):

I think, You use `Session["ID"]=HF_Reg_Id.Value.ToString();` and Redirect to VanRegister.aspx then check `if(Session["ID"]!=null)` continue. Good luck.

Comment: Session["ID"] = HF_Reg_Id.Value.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("VanRegister.aspx?id= " + ID);

Comment: Session["ID"] = HF_Reg_Id.Value.ToString(); Response.Redirect("VanRegister.aspx"); behind code PageLoad "VanRegister.aspx" - if(Session["ID"]!=null) {...}

Comment: Session is not appropriate for this. Passing the ID is unique to this client-server interaction, not a property of the session. It makes more sense to pass it via URL. Passing it via session could result in unexpected behavior if the client has more than one tab/window open on the site at a time.